# CSS issue. Using an MVC view

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

I want to override a CSS setting on a form. I'm using bootstrap and I have my own custom CSS file that I have to do the override.

However, I see that it does not bring in my custom css file and does not reference the Bootstrap version rule for .form-control. Instead it is using a "forms.less" file that I don't even know where it is. It's not in my content folder. Though the pic indicates it is in the Contents\Less folder.

[image]

[image]

Here is the Content folder.

[image]

Here is the bundling. My custom site.css follows bootstrap.

[image]

Here is my custom CSS file and the .form-control rule where I am overriding the witdh.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add this at the bottom of my view. @Styles.Render("~/Content/css"). I thought having this in the _Layout_cshtml would take care of it. So not sure why I have to do it twice.

Answer (score 0):

You have to Overriding using the !important.

```
.form-control{
  width: 0px !important;
}
```

for more details please check below url:
https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/css/how-to-override-css-styles.html

Comment: Niraj. I tried that but it did nothing as my custom Site.css file is not being brought in and it still references that "forms.less".

Comment: I had to add this at the bottom of my view. @Styles.Render("~/Content/css"). I thought having this in the _Layout_cshtml would take care of it. So not sure why I have to do it twice.

Comment: @user3020047 Please check the load order of the CSS by using ctrl + u (view-source). let me know what you got.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to override your custom css , then use it after bootstrap css.

Comment: kgajjar: I want my custom CSS to take affect - not Bootstrap. I have the custom CSS following the bootstrap CSS in the bundleConfig.cs.

Comment: @user3020047 make your custom CSS and call it after bootstrap CSS . So , your custom CSS will override the bootstrap css.